# Exibir registro mais atual sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-select

estou tentar buscar o somente o último registro (última venda)de cada cliente e não estou obtendo êxito. Tentei de várias formas, mas nada..Só retorna todas as vendas a partir da data.
Segue minha query.
Agradeço a ajuda.

```
use banco
select m.cli_forn,c.nome,c.telefone,c.fax,m.num_nf,max(convert(date,m.dt_mov))as Data,m.valor_mov,m.cod_vendedor
from tb_movimentos m inner join tb_cliente c on(c.cod_cli=m.cli_forn)

where m.cod_vendedor = '178' and c.cod_cli !='5000' and status_clifor = 'C'and m.dt_mov >='2015-01-01' 
group by  m.cli_forn,c.nome,c.telefone,c.fax,m.num_nf,m.valor_mov,m.cod_vendedor
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: algo no group by não está agrupando como espera, pode colocar um exemplo dos dados que retorna?

Comment: Como está declarada a coluna `dt_mov`? Pode existir mais de uma venda para o mesmo cliente no mesmo dia? A coluna `status_clifor` é de qual tabela?

Answer (score 1):

Eis uma solução clássica:

```
-- código #1
USE banco;

with UltMov as (
SELECT *,
       seq= row_number() over (partition by cli_forn order by dt_mov desc)
  from tb_movimentos
  where status_clifor = 'C' 
        and dt_mov >= '20150101'
)  
SELECT C.cod_cli, C.nome, C.telefone, C.fax, 
       M.num_nf, M.dt_mov, M.valor_mov, M.cod_vendedor
  from tb_cliente as C
       inner join UltMov as M on M.cli_forn = C.cod_cli
  where M.seq = 1;
```

Não testei; pode ter algum erro.

Comment: Só tirei o and do primeiro where e filtrei por vendedor. PREFECT!!  Obrigado!!!

Comment: Ops! Tinha um "and" perdido ali...